# Telephone Number Validation Error Magento 1.8.1

Tags: validation

I am getting a "This is a required field" error during customer checkout when the customer enters a phone number with hyphens are parenthesis. When special characters are not used it works without issues. Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Telephone field is actually using a `number` input type:

```
<input type="number" name="billing[telephone]" value="" title="Telephone" class="input-text  required-entry form-control validation-failed" id="billing:telephone">
```

[The `number` type only supports floating-point numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) - an input value like `555-555-5555` isn't a proper `number`, so the browser clears out the field right before Magento validates the `input`.  The value is blank, so it displays the "required field" validation message.

Try using [`type="tel"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html) or `type="text"` instead, and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Do you know what file I would find this code in? Thank you !!!!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the file and it worked. Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  If you could mark this answer as Accepted (click the check mark) I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The validations are placed in `js/prototype/validation.js` file

The exact validation for phone is as:

```
['validate-phoneStrict', 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.', function(v) {
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/.test(v);
            }],
```

Try using phoneStrict validation.

I am checking on magento 1.9 and 1.8 version